# How to write VBA Code to add Digital Signature to protect VBAProject?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I have searched the MSDN, it only gives an example how to add digital signature to protect the entire workbook:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Signatures.AddNonVisibleSignature "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
```

but VBAProject does not contain any method to add a signature, the only way is:

Steps for manual:

1. Open excel file --> Alt + F11 (to open VBA project)
2. Tools --> Digital Signature --> Choose --> Select Certificate --> OK
3. Save

Is there any way to do this pragmatically, or any other suggestions?

Comment: have you seen that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194230/how-to-assign-certificates-to-excel-macros-programmatically).

Comment: @KazJaw Yes, but this macro will run at server, I can not simulate all the needed steps to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to use VSTO using c#.net or vb.net ,coz the vba is limited and will not doing everything you desire,so have alook on vsto...